# AJAX to check the login name exists or not

Tags: php, ajax, mysql, jquery, authentication

i have a login box...

when the user starts typing.. i want to check whether the LOGIN NAME entered exists in the database or not...

*if the login name is exist i am going to set the login button active... if it doesnot exist i am going to set the login button deactive...*

offcourse i am going to need **AJAX** to perform my **mySQL** via **PHP** tough i don't know how it will be done...

lets say this is my query

```
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name='mytextboxvalue'"); 
?>
```

how to do it

Comment: So you give an attacker a good hint if a username is worth attacking or not?

Comment: my page is only available on intrAnet.. plus haven't you seen sign-up forms where this thing is done

Comment: This question is too broad. It's actually "Teach me what is AJAX and how to use it". Buy yourself a book, browse to some online tutorial. And ask certain question when you will have one.

Comment: Google just released something like this, http://www.google.com/instant/ perhaps ask them ask. :-P

Comment: @jakenoble, what Google have done with instant is not the same at all, what Google have done is create an Ajax based result system, where when you click search it fetches new results via Ajax, what the OP wishes to do is to enable / disable an element depending on an Ajax result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep it simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Form = $('#myForm');
    var Input = $('input.username',Form)

    Input.change(function(event){
        Value = Input.val();
        if(Value.length > 5)
        {
            $.getJSON('/path/to/username_check.php',{username:Value},function(response){
                if(response.valid == true)
                {
                    Form.find('input[type*=submit]').attr('disabled','false');
                }else
                {
                     Form.find('input[type*=submit]').attr('disabled','true');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and then PHP side..

```
<?php
//Load DB Connections etc.
if(!empty($_REQUEST['username']))
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['username']);

    if(isset($_SESSION['username_tmp'][$username]))
    {
        echo json_encode(array('valid' => (bool)$_SESSION['username_tmp'][$username]));
        die();
    }
    //Check the database here... $num_rows being a validation var from mysql_result
    $_SESSION['username_tmp'][$username] = ($num_rows == 0) ? true : false;

    echo json_encode(array('valid' => (bool)$_SESSION['username_tmp'][$username]));
    die();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON-RPC, here is [implementation in php](http://jsonrpcphp.org/).
and in JQuery you can use this code.

```
var id = 1;
function check_login(){
  var request = JSON.stringify({'jsonrpc': '2.0',
                       'method': 'login_check', 
                       'params': [$('#login_box').val()],
                       'id': id++});
  $.ajax({url: "json_rpc.php", 
        data: request,
        success: function(data) {
          if (data) {
            $('#login_button').removeAttr('disabled');
          } else {
            $('#login_button').attr('disabled', true);
          }
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type:"POST"});
}
```

and in php

```
<?php

include 'jsonRPCServer.php';
//mysql_connect 
//mysql_select_db
class Service {
  public function login_check($login) {
     $login = mysql_real_escape_string($login);
     $id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name='$login'");
     return mysql_num_rows($id) != 0;
  }
}


$service = new Service();

jsonRPCServer::handle($service);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at jQuery [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) and jQuery [TypeWatch](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TypeWatch)

But like @halfdan said, this is a potential security risk. I have never seen a site do this with a username, only with search results.

Your potentially giving away an end point (URL) on your web site which anyone could query to find out if a username is valid. Intranet or not, it is a risk.